# How to remove the empty nodes in C# or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, treeview, parent-child

I am trying to remove the empty nodes from the list in C#. I am trying to make a  structure like tree view but due to some issues I need to have the node removed and it’s coming as Null.

```
var tree = [{
    Id: 1,
    text: "Parent 1",
    ParentId: 0
    nodes: [{
        Id: 2,
        text: "Child 1",
        ParentId: 1
        nodes: [{
            Id: 3
            text: "Grandchild 1",
            ParentId: 2,
            nodes: []
          },
          {
            Id: 4,
            text: "Grandchild 2",
            ParentId: 2,
            nodes: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Id: 5
        text: "Child 2",
        ParentId: 1,
        nodes: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 6,
    text: "Parent 2",
    ParentId: 0
    nodes: []
  }
];
```

How to remove the empty nodes in C# or JavaScript?

Comment: check array length if its 0 use "delete" to remove that property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Comment: Its not a Array.its a List

Comment: list like List<TreeObject> ListNode = new List<TreeObject>();

Comment: In javascript we called list as arrary

Comment: you want to do it in C# or javascript

Comment: i wont to do it in C#

Comment: can you share your js code

Answer (score 0):

To delete a property from an object you may use [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

To remove empty `nodes` from your `tree`, you could loop recursively through the tree and remove `nodes` when his `length` is zero, see follow:

```js
var tree = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nodes: [
        {
          id: 2,
          nodes: [
            {
              id: 3,
              nodes: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          nodes: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      nodes: []
    }
];

function traverse(obj) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (!!obj[key] && typeof(obj[key])=="object") {
            if(key==="nodes"){
              var nodesLen = obj[key].length;
              if(nodesLen == 0){
                delete obj[key];
              }
            }
            traverse(obj[key]);
        }
    }
} 

console.log("BEFORE");
console.log(tree);

traverse(tree);

console.log("AFTER");
console.log(tree);
```

I hope it helps you. Bye